# Create VLANs only if they don't exist on a Nexus switch

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create an Ansible playbook which should create VLANs defined in file vlans.dat on a Cisco Nexus switch only when they don't exist on device.

File vlans.dat contains:

```
---
vlans:
  - { vlan_id: 2, name: TEST }
```

And Ansible file:

```
---
- name: Verify and create VLANs
  hosts: switches_group
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - vlans.dat
  tasks:
     - name: Get Nexus facts
       nxos_facts:
       register: data
     - name: Create new VLANs only
       nxos_vlan:
        vlan_id: "{{ item.vlan_id }}"
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        state:   "{{item.state | default('present') }}"
       with_items: "{{ vlans }}"
       when:  item.vlan_id not in data.ansible_facts.vlan_list
```

In the when statement I'm trying to limit execution only to the case when `vlan_id` (defined in the file) doesn't exist in the `vlan_list` gathered by `nxos_facts` module. Unfortunately it gets executed even when the `vlan_id` already exists in the `vlan_list` and I don't know why?

```
PLAY [Verify and create VLANs]     
TASK [Get Nexus facts] 
 ok: [10.1.1.1]
TASK [Create new VLANs only] 
 ok: [10.1.1.1] => (item={u'name': u'TEST', u'vlan_id': 2})
TASK [debug] 
 skipping: [10.1.1.1]

PLAY RECAP 
 10.1.1.1   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0 failed=0
```

Can you help me with that or provide some solution what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the value of `vlan_list` to see what it contains, and can you share that output with us? `- debug: var=data.ansible_facts.vlan_list verbosity=0`

Comment: Yes, I've checked it and it contains only VLAN ID's list (collected by nxos_facts module) existing on a switch. `TASK [debug] *******
ok: [10.1.1.1] => {
    "data.ansible_facts.vlan_list": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "10",
        "11",
        "12",
        "13",
        "14",
        "105",
...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have stumbled upon a side-effect of YAML having actual types. Because in `{vlan_id: 2}` the 2 is an `int` but the list is strings. As you might imagine `{{ 1 in ["1"] }}` is `False`.

There are two ways out of that situation: make the `vlan_id` a string via `- { vlan_id: "2" }` or coerce the `vlan_id` to a string just for testing the list membership:

```
when:  (item.vlan_id|string) not in data.ansible_facts.vlan_list
```

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that significant detail. After converting vlan_id to string everything started to work properly.